# python regex if some words contain spaces

Tags: python, regex, replace, split

Problem example:

```
str1 = "ur a sh * tty comment ."
```

I need each word from the sentence and wanted to replace `sh * tty` with `sh***tty` (replace those spaces inside word with `*`)

If I try:

```
for word in s.split():
    print(word)
```

I get:

```
ur
a
sh
*
tty
comment
.
```

`sh * tty` is now split into 3 words

1. `sh`
2. `*`
3. `tty`

But I need exactly this word `sh * tty` so then I can replace spaces with `*` and make it `sh***tty` finally.

I can't simply replace spaces with `*`. I just needed to replace a space with `*` if that space is inside any English word (typical mistake).

I also tried:

```
s = "ur a sh * tty comment ."
makeBad = s.translate ({ord(c): "*" for c in " "})
```

But I wanted not to replace spaces that separate 2 words.

Comment: How do you know where a word starts? Maybe any two chunks of text on both sides of `*`? Try `re.sub(r'\S+ +\* +\S+', lambda x: x.group().replace(' ', '*') , str1)`. Or just `re.sub(r'(\S) (\*) (\S)', '***' , str1)` if there are single spaces around `*`.

Comment: re.sub(r'(\S) (\*) (\S)', '***' , str1)  it might will be just fine for me,,but in that case it is possible that sometimes i will get sh % tty? then it won't work. can you modify your second code a bit so it assigns 3 asterisk when in a word i will see anything from this list? "!@#$%^&()[]{};:,./<>?\|`~-=_+" also the first solution too that you propose?

Comment: Like ``nw = r"[]\s!@#$%^&()[{};:,./<>?\\|`~=_+-]"`` and then ``print( re.sub(rf'(\S){nw}\*{nw}(\S)', r'\1***\2' , str1) )``? See https://ideone.com/4FLT2r

Comment: for sh @ tty it didn't work

Comment: Ah, got it, you need https://ideone.com/rtC2nb: ``nw = r"[]*!@#$%^&()[{};:,./<>?\\|`~=_+-]"`` and then ``print( re.sub(rf'(\S) {nw} (\S)', r'\1***\2' , str1) )``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
str1 = "ur a sh * tty comment ."
nw = r"[]*!@#$%^&()[{};:,./<>?\\|`~=_+-]"
print( re.sub(rf'(\S) {nw} (\S)', r'\1***\2' , str1) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rtC2nb).

Here, the pattern will look like

```
(\S) []*!@#$%^&()[{};:,./<>?\\|`~=_+-] (\S)
```

It matches

- `(\S)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any non-whitespace char
- - a space
- `` []*!@#$%^&()[{};:,./<>?\\|`~=_+-] `` - a char form the set: `` ]*!@#$%^&()[{};:,./<>?\|`~=_+- ``
- - a space
- `(\S)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any non-whitespace char.

Comment: thank you a lot..it helps..1 last worst case scenario,can you please help me with that? consider this code : https://pastebin.com/ApgHYLmF the output is "f k u" and i wanted f**k u" or exactly what we have in dataset1 . can you modify that code for me so i get output like this?

Comment: i got error though but the code is like this : https://ideone.com/zqL6RN  and the output i get is "need f k u" but i am seeking for a way to replace f k there with * that will replace spaces,you got it?

Comment: @MobassirHossen No idea what your  criteria here would be for matching. What is the rule?

Comment: me too can't think about a rule but the output is something that i wanted like that but can't think about a rule in that case for assigning * just inside word where we have space,,i will use your solution then, but now i won't be able to delete those unnecessary words like a,an the etc that doesn't define any sentiment,i wanted to remove those unnecessary words using nltk and PorterStemmer and then on new string i wanted to replace things like "sh * tty" with sh***tty like you provided above

Comment: just now found a solution,,using your regex on such row comments to convert sh * t to sh***t and then pass that new string to nltk or PorterStemmer  for removing unnecessary words,many many thanks for your help